# How do you find a match inside of a match using regular expressions in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex

How do you find a match inside of a match?

With the following string

```
@function("something") @anotherFunction("moreStuff" "andMore") "evenMore"
```

I'm trying the capture the things in quotes as well as the the function names. The outcome I'm looking for is:

**Match 1**

```
Group 1: function
Group 2: something
Group 3: undefined
```

**Match 2**

```
Group 1: anotherFunction
Group 2: moreStuff andMore
Group 3: undefined
```

**Match 3**

```
Group 1: undefined
Group 2: undefined
Group 3: evenMore
```

I can manage to get everything in quotes using the expression below but I'm not sure how to capture the right groups when looking for matches that exist inside the functions.

```
\"([^\"]*)\" *
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/Jpm3yvsOkEPWoDWB)

Comment: By the way I'm not sure what the correct way to explain this is. I've read up on regular expressions and wasn't able to find something that answered this scenario.

Comment: http://regex101.com/r/iX5xR2/3  you can try this.you will to strip your results of " though

Comment: What's the regex (and code) you used to get these three matches?

Comment: I haven't been able to get those matches, I've just written it like that to help explain what I'm after. The best I can do is https://www.debuggex.com/r/SB7eOgFnu_-efHrb/8 but it's not doing what I'd want it to do.

Comment: Thanks @vks I've thought about doing it like this by spliting the string into an array and then running another regex on each string in the array.